# Keep items with same keys in two dictionary and discard other items

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to remove all non-matching items (values with different keys) in two dicts `dict_a` and `dict_b`. What is a better way of achieving this?

Example:

```
dict_a = {key1: x1, key2: y1, key4: z1}
dict_b = {key1: x2, key3: y2, key4: w1}
# becomes:
# dict_a = {key1: x1, key4: z1}
# dict_b = {key1: x2, key4: w1}
```

My attempt:

```py
keep_keys = [keyA for keyA in dict_a.keys() if keyA in dict_b.keys()]

for i in dict_b.copy().keys():
    if i not in keep_keys:
        del dict_b[i]

for i in dict_a.copy().keys():
    if i not in keep_keys:
        del dict_a[i]
```

I am looking for shorter (pythonic) way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```py
d1 = {"key1": "x1", "key2": "y1", "key4": "z1"}
d2 = {"key1": "x2", "key3": "y2", "key4": "w1"}

common_keys = d1.keys() & d2.keys()

d1 = {k: d1[k] for k in common_keys}
d2 = {k: d2[k] for k in common_keys}

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

Prints:

```
{'key1': 'x1', 'key4': 'z1'}
{'key1': 'x2', 'key4': 'w1'}
```

Comment: Accepting as answer. Exactly what I want + removes `del` from code. One question, when I run this code, my output is reversed for some reason. `/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/ria1/test.py 
{'key4': 'z1', 'key1': 'x1'}
{'key4': 'w1', 'key1': 'x2'}`

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: That is because `d1.keys() & d2.keys()` returns a `set` which is an unordered collection by design, so when looping over it in the dict comprehension, it just takes "whatever order it does"

Comment: @R__i_ The `common_keys` is set, so it's unordered by definition. It shouldn't matter, but you can always sort the common_keys if you want.

Comment: @Andrej Another option: `d1 = {k: v for k,v in d1.items() if k in common_keys}`

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, I had the answer written first like that :) But it's more efficient to just iterate over common_keys. However, its option.

Answer (score 3):

It's not **a lot** better, but this uses a so-called "dictionary comprehension" to achieve it. It's effectively a `for` loop in one line (but two lines here since we have two dictionaries).

```py
dict_a = {k: v for k, v in dict_a.items() if k in dict_b}
dict_b = {k: v for k, v in dict_b.items() if k in dict_a}
```

This below also works, and is technically shorter but (maybe?) less Pythonic

```
dict_a = {k: dict_a[k] for k in dict_a if k in dict_b}
dict_b = {k: dict_b[k] for k in dict_b if k in dict_a}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you flip the problem into removing non-shared keys, it becomes a bit easier: get non-shared keys using XOR (setlike), then delete them where they occur.

```
d1 = {'key1': 'x1', 'key2': 'y1', 'key4': 'z1'}
d2 = {'key1': 'x2', 'key3': 'y2', 'key4': 'w1'}

discard_keys = d1.keys() ^ d2.keys()
for k in discard_keys:
    if k in d1:
        del d1[k]
    if k in d2:
        del d2[k]

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

```
{'key1': 'x1', 'key4': 'z1'}
{'key1': 'x2', 'key4': 'w1'}
```